# PHP Distance between two points latitude longitude

Tags: php, math

I am after a very simple distance between two 2D points function for PHP.

For example `lat`, `lng` of `-50000.00,400.00`. This is a flat surface, no need calculate for the earth circumference.

I have tried all sorts of solutions for this and none of them work correctly. I do not know why but when `lat` or `lng` is > `~240.00` the result starts going backwards as if the distance is too great to calculate. Even the online calculators fail to calculate a large distance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have googled an found following links. These might help you. http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php  http://www.techrecite.com/distance-formula-in-php-calculate-distance-between-two-points-programmatically/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is more a mathematical problem.

I think you can have a first distance solution with tranlation of general formula:

https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html

You have to create a PHP function that make the square the difference for each axis, then sum them up and take the square root.

Alternatively, you can make the follow:

http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php

Let me know if you need help!

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, but.....

echo distance(200.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") . " Miles<br>";

Returns..... 
11839.196960717 Miles

AND

echo distance(500.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") . " Miles<br>";
7702.347823328 Miles

Obviously the distance is much greater.

This is the issue I am having with almost all the functions I have tried with large numbers.

The mathsisfun link I have in my browser for a couple of days and would be perfect if I could work out the php math :)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct, but I am getting a much better result.

echo(sqrt(($X2 - $X1) + ($Y2 - $Y1)));

Comment: I think it's right! It depends on your task. :)

Comment: @DaniloCosta This is not an answer, as the distance between 2 coordinates on a 2D plane is not the same as the distance between 2 coordinates that are projected on a sphere (i.e. you might get correct answers at the equator, but as you go towards the poles, your answers will be exaggerated).